# SwiftUI 2.0: export images with .fileExporter modifier

Tags: swiftui, ios14, xcode12, macos-big-sur

Goal: export images with SwiftUI using the new .fileExporter modifier

Problem: The target image is not passing to .fileExporter document.

Question: How can I get .fileExporter modifier to export images?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var openFile = false
    @State private var exportFile = false


    @State private var img1 = UIImage()
    @State private var img2 = UIImage()

    @State private var target: Binding<UIImage>?    // dynamic target for importer
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            //image 1
            Button(action: {
                    self.target = $img1
                self.openFile.toggle()
            }){
                
                Image(uiImage: self.img1)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            
            //image 2
            Button(action: {
                    self.target = $img2
                self.openFile.toggle()
            }){
                
                Image(uiImage: self.img2)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("File Importer")


        //file exporter not working. not sure what I should input as "document"
        .fileExporter(isPresented: $exportFile, document: target, contentType: .image) { result in
            if case .success = result {
                // Handle success.
            } else {
                // Handle failure.
            }
        }

        //file importer
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [.image]) { (res) in
            do{
                let fileUrl = try res.get()
                print(fileUrl)
                
                guard fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else { return }
                if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl),
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    self.target?.wrappedValue = image
                }
                fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                
            } catch{
                
                print ("error reading")
                print (error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a couple of code problems and a couple of logic problems that I found.  Here's my edited version:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var openFile = false
    @State private var exportFile = false


    @State private var img1 = UIImage(named: "0")!
    @State private var img2 = UIImage(named: "1")!

    @State private var target : UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            //image 1
            Button(action: {
                self.target = img1
                self.exportFile.toggle()
                //self.openFile.toggle()
            }){
                
                Image(uiImage: self.img1)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            
            //image 2
            Button(action: {
                self.target = img2
                self.exportFile.toggle()
                //self.openFile.toggle()
            }){
                
                Image(uiImage: self.img2)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("File Importer")

        .fileExporter(isPresented: $exportFile, document: ImageDocument(image: target), contentType: .png, onCompletion: { (result) in
            if case .success = result {
                print("Success")
            } else {
                print("Failure")
            }
        })


        //file importer
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $openFile, allowedContentTypes: [.image]) { (res) in
            do{
                let fileUrl = try res.get()
                print(fileUrl)
                
                guard fileUrl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else { return }
                if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: fileUrl),
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
                    self.target = image
                }
                fileUrl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                
            } catch{
                
                print ("error reading")
                print (error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ImageDocument: FileDocument {
    
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.png] }

    var image: UIImage

    init(image: UIImage?) {
        self.image = image ?? UIImage()
    }

    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents,
              let image = UIImage(data: data)
        else {
            throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
        }
        self.image = image
    }

    func fileWrapper(configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        return FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: image.pngData()!)
    }
    
}
```

Things to look at:

1. Logic error: you had an `exportFile` state variable, but you never modified it. That would mean `fileExporter` would never present.
2. You were passing a `Binding<UIImage>` to a function that wants a `FileDocument`. I wrote a simple `FileDocument` implementation for images.
3. Because I switched out your `openFile` toggles for `exportFile`, you now don't have any `openFile` access. That's a logic decision for you to figure out when/how to trigger those.
4. I also didn't do any error handling for the images and made a decision to treat everything as a PNG. You may want to make different choices.

Note that I also used images named "0" and "1" -- those were specific to my sample project. Change those to fit what works for your project.

If you want a different type of solution to this, you can also look at using the `\.exportFiles` action: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-export-files-using-exportfilesaction

Comment: thanks!!! do you know how to export multiple images in a folder? tried but didn't work...

Comment: You would have to write your own solution to export and not use fileExporter.  fileExporter is for one document at a time (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/group/fileexporter(ispresented:document:contenttype:defaultfilename:oncompletion:)-41uhb). This is assuming you're looking to export them as separate files. If you want to export them as a bundle, you could look into doing that -- might be a good second question, though, and not one I have expertise with

Comment: thanks again! I posted another question. Goal is to export one folder with something like 5 images